# default value of title block set to controller name in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In a cakephp layout I fetch a block in order to set the title of the page like so

```
<title>Example - <?php echo $this->fetch('title');?></title>
```

I have noticed that unless I create a block 'title' in a view or assign some value to the block, the value of title always corresponds to the name of the controller. I have not found this behaviour documented anywhere. Is there any way to change this? My cakePHP version is 2.7.5.

Comment: can you tell me which version of cake are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a default value to be output by `$this->fetch()` if a value hasn't already been assigned using the second parameter:-

```
echo $this->fetch('title', 'Default title');
```

To override the default just use `$this->assign()` in your view (before `$this->fetch()` is called):-

```
$this->assign('title', 'Overridden title');
```

Comment: thank you.. it appears though that $this->fetch('title') _does_ return a default value, the name of the corresponding controller.. therefore the default value is of no use.. why does $this->fetch('title') return a default value? Can you confirm this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
class ExampleController extends AppController {

   // Set title in default for all this controller methods
   public $title = "Your title";

   // Override the title by setting title in method
   public function

        $this->set('title', 'Your title');
   }
}
```

In your layout or view

```
cakephp 2.x
<?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?>

cakephp 3.x
<?= $this->fetch('title'); ?>
```